# Azure functions - cannot be imported again. It was already imported at... (nuget, .net core 2.1) - a StackOverflow error

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, stack-overflow

**Hello,**

I have a .net core 2.1 web app.  I added to the solution an Azure Function app.
My function app references my web app (so I may access the entity framework classes).
**For some reason I have a Stack Overflow error.**

If I do not reference the web app, then there is no problem.

If I reference a new .netstandard 2 class library there is no problem.

I am using azure-functions-core-tools 2.4.419.

```
Warning 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning MSB4011 "C:\Users\[myusername]\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.0.2\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.props" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Code\Apps\Rubbish\WebAppWithFunctions\TestFunctionApp\obj\TestFunctionApp.csproj.nuget.g.props (17,5)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [C:\Code\Apps\Rubbish\WebAppWithFunctions\TestFunctionApp\TestFunctionApp.csproj] TestFunctionApp     38  

Warning 2

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning MSB4011 "C:\Users\[username]\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.0.2\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Code\Apps\Rubbish\WebAppWithFunctions\TestFunctionApp\obj\TestFunctionApp.csproj.nuget.g.targets (9,5)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [C:\Code\Apps\Rubbish\WebAppWithFunctions\TestFunctionApp\TestFunctionApp.csproj]    TestFunctionApp     60  

Warning 3:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning         TestFunctionApp C:\Users\[username]\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.0.2\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets   20  

Warning 4:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException.   TestFunctionApp C:\Users\[username]\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.0.2\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets   20  

Error 1:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Metadata generation failed. TestFunctionApp C:\Users\[username]\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.0.2\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets   20
```

My CSProj of my web app

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"  />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Nuget packages installed on web app are:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design 2.1.2
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1
```

Thanks in advance,
Dan.

Comment: Consider moving the EF pieces out to a separate.Net Standard assembly and reference this from both the web app and the function.

Comment: Totally agree with this - was my original plan, but I wanted to know why this happened before using it in my production app - I tried what you suggested in another application and it worked fine.  But I found myself wondering why adding a simple reference to a web app would break it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the same configuration i tried in my machine VS 2017. It worked for me

[image]

Can you check what is the SDK you have in your Azure function. For me it is working with Microsoft.NetCore.App 2.2.0.

Here is the screenshot for the same.

[image]

Try to upgrade your Azure function tool using Choco command

```
choco upgrade azure-functions-core-tools
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: My web app and function are 2.1 not 2.2